# Hide banner if I click on Read now, and don't show it again

Tags: bug, banner

Got this banner, like everyone else
[image]

You can interact with it in two ways:

1. `Read now`
2. `x` to close

If I close it, I never see it again
But if I click `Read now`, I keep seeing the banner, and I **have** to click on `x` to never see it again.

I suggest to stop showing the banner if user interacted with it

Comment: It does go away but only initially, it will show again if you open up a new page.

Comment: block it with ublock, usually it's just useless podcasts or uninteresting things. Plus it's always in the Blog header on the right side as well. those banners take forever to go away, and if you visit any other site on the network you see it again

Comment: `I suggest to stop showing the banner` Simplified it for you